# What is the standard data format for transferring IQ data between interfaces?

Tags: analog-to-digital, software-defined-radio

I've seen IQ data typically combined within a single 32 bit word when sending streams of data between different components. (i.e. I & Q are both signed fixed point integers with 16 bit word length and 15 bit fraction length.) Is there a standard for this, or is this just common practice to format it this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit of both standard/common practice but it also depends on how you design your system.

In a 32-bit word where complex values are two 16-bit fixed-point values, using 15 bits for the fractional part and one bit for the sign is very common (note there is no dedicated integer bit). This is because these values allow you to map a 16-bit word to the range $[-1, 0.999969482421875]]$, which is essentially a range of $[-1, 1]$. From here, you can scale as you'd like.

Comment: This is a very sensible format _if your data is close to 16 bits/word_, and it's something that's going to work well for a whole lot of current (ca 2024) radio systems.  So, yes, "it depends on how you design your system".  If for some reason you had really noisy data and needed lots of speed then you'd want fewer bits.  If for some reason you had really quiet data (i.e., you're sampling something at 40Hz with a 24-bit ADC, don't ask me why) then you'd want more.

Comment: @TimWescott My assumption was that the OP only wanted to know why a 16-bit fixed-point value would be re-interpreted this way. Not necessarily the setup around the ADC, as this is agnostic to that.